# how to index properly in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I've been given this question for my university assignment

```
Find the title, publisher, publication year and price of the books with a given book title.
```

and this question has its own set of sub questions

```
1.) Create an index that speeds up processing of a query consistent with a pattern.

2) Apply a method getIndexes() to list all existing indexes,

3) Apply a method explain()to verify whether the system plans to use the indexes created for processing of a query consistent with a pattern

4)  Drop an index created in Step 1 with a method dropIndex()
```

This was my attempt at said questions

```
//task1
db.bookstore.createIndex( {"book.title":1}, 
{"unique":false} );

//task 2
db.bookstore.getIndexes();

//task 3
db.bookstore.find({"book.title": "Algorithms"}).explain(); //uses the index?

//task 4
db.bookshop.dropIndex("indexName");
```

All of these work without any issues however im unsure if im doing it properly? any insight is appreciated

JS file that contains the information on "books".

```
db.bookshop.insert( {
    "_id":"185.3.16",
    "book": {
        "callnum":"185.3.16",
        "isbn":"1-292-06118-9",
        "title":"Database Systems",
        "authors":[
            {
                "fname":"Thomas",
                "lname":"Connolly"},
            { 
                "fname":"Carolyn",
                "lname":"Begg"}
        ],
        "publisher":"Pearson Pty Ltd",
        "year":2015,
        "price":136.99,
        "topic":"Computer Science",
        "description":"This is the 6th edition. You can register online to access the examples",
        "keywords":["Database", "XML", "Distributed"]
        }
});

db.bookshop.insert( {
    "_id":"163.24.12",
    "book": {
        "callnum":"163.24.12",
        "isbn":"1-123-456-810",
        "title":"Core Java",
        "authors":[
            {
                "fname":"Horstmann",
                "lname":"Cornell"}
        ],
        "publisher":"PH Pty Ltd",
        "year":2012,
        "price":142.90,
        "topic":"Computer Science",
        "description":"It covers JAVA programming and JAVA script",
        "keywords":["JAVA", "XML", "Script"]
    }
});

db.bookshop.insert( {
    "_id":"123.45.67",
    "book": {
        "callnum":"123.45.67",
        "isbn":"1-123-456-789",
        "title":"Algorithms",
        "authors":[
            {
                "fname":"James",
                "lname":"Bond"},
            {
                "fname":"Harry",
                "lname":"Potter"},
            {
                "fname":"William",
                "lname":"Stallings"}
        ],
        "publisher":"Pearson Pty Ltd",
        "year":2013,
        "price":65.85,
        "topic":"Computer Science",
        "description":"It contains algorithms and their applications. You can download examples from the website"
    }
});
```

Comment: Which part or parts are you unsure about? It looks like the answer to question 3 should allow you to verify if the answer to 1 is correct. Likewise, 2 can be used to verify the answer to 4.

Comment: @AdamHarrison  Im unsure of the part  Find the title, publisher, publication year and price. Im assuming the index is only for title(see updated answer) but would finding the data be part of question 3?

Comment: @AdamHarrison Also to add, if i was too index the year would that be a single key index?

Comment: An index on just `"book.year"` would not be a multi-key index since it isn't on an array field. Is that what you were asking? A easy way to think about it is that there's only a single value being indexed per document. Regarding the query; try to start off with just a simple query and go from there. For example, what would the query look like if you wanted to find the book with the title "Database Systems"? Once that is done, how can you modify the query so that it only returns those four fields?

Comment: so if i did db.bookstore.createIndex( {"book.title":1} for example. Would i just do db.bookstore.find({book.title: "example},{book.publisher:"example"}.etc);

Comment: Very close. The query would be: `db.bookstore.find({ "book.title" : "example" }, { "book.publisher" : 1, ... } )`, as the projection part of a query (i.e. specifying which fields to return) uses the 0 / 1 syntax, similar to an index (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

Comment: In regards to indexing, it is generally good practice to index all of the fields that are being used to filter or sort. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/